# Get Resources using JSOM - nested executeQueryAsync()

Tags: project-server, client-object-model

I am trying to access the calendar exception for each resource, but I'm having some trouble with the nested executeQueryAsync() calls.

Here's a piece of my code:

App.js

```
// Get the collection of enterprise resources.
function GetResources()
{   
    // Display a message to the user to show we are reading the resources. 
    $('#spanMessage').text('Reading resources...');

    // Initialize the current client context.
    projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();

    // Get the collection of enterprise resources.
    resources = projContext.get_enterpriseResources();

    // Register the request for information.
    projContext.load(resources);

    // Run the request on the server.
    projContext.executeQueryAsync(IterateThroughResources, QueryFailed);
}

function IterateThroughResources(response)
{
    // Get the enumerator and iterate through the collection.
    var enumerator = resources.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var resource = enumerator.get_current();
        var resourceId = resource.get_id(); 
        var resourceName = resource.get_name();

        // Get the collection of calendar exceptions.
        var exceptions = resource.get_resourceCalendarExceptions();

        // Register the request for information that you want to run on the server.
        projContext.load(exceptions);

        projContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){IterateThroughCalendarExceptions(resource, exceptions);}), QueryFailed);
    }
}

function IterateThroughCalendarExceptions(resource, exceptions)
{
    var enumerator = exceptions.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var exception = enumerator.get_current();
        var name = exception.get_name();
    }
}
```

But the fact that it's running asynchronous it's a problem, because the IterateThroughCalendarExceptions seems to always receive the same params.

Comment: How to get EDR or RBS value of Resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix by making a change in the code. 
Insted of making a request on the server for every resource, I register the request for information (.load) for every resource and then run one request on the server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing, very good solution! I cannot believe that I haven't proposed it myself :) Got locked with this create-functions-inside-loop thing, it was one thing I had once been struggling a lot with and I noticed it from the first glance. Hopefully this still be a good hint for you for your farther JS development ;) P.S. Please mark this as an accepted answer so that people can see it is what they need if they have same problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I can't mark this as the accepted answer yet because of the few points I have. It seems I will be able to accept my own answer tomorrow.

Comment: Can you post a sample code of that solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is a quite well-known JS inconvenience and described in detail for example here:

- http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/04/creating-javascript-function-inside.html

In brief, creating functions in loops is tricky. In your case the callback function `function(){IterateThroughCalendarExceptions(resource, exceptions);}` will always use `resource` & `exceptions` values from the last iteration of the loop.

To prevent that, you have to wrap your function like that:

```
projContext.executeQueryAsync(
  (function()
  {
     IterateThroughCalendarExceptions(resource, exceptions);
  })(resource, exceptions),
  QueryFailed);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. That was what I was looking for. But I was able to fix it in another way, which is what I should have done from the start. I'm loading calendar exceptions for every resource and running only one request on the server

Answer (score 1):

Try using an Include to eager load the exceptions:

```
projContext.load(resources, "Include(ID, Name, ResourceCalendarExceptions)");
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I had to change "ID" to "Id" because I was getting the following error when calling `resource.get_id();` "The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized sharepoint"